# Undesired scroll bars on new tags page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tagging, design

I don't think we want the scroll bars on https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new to be there:

[image: undesired scroll bars]
(I decreased the text size slightly to make the entire area fit my laptop screen, but the behavior remains at 100% text zoom.)

I'm using Firefox 10.0 on Windows 7 and in case it matters, my screen has a resolution of 1366x768.

Edit:

1. See my comment to Martin Schröder.
2. This problem also occurs in Safari 5.1.2 on Windows 7 (where I don't think I have any add-ons).

Comment: I *don't* get the scroll bars with FF 10 on a with Mac 10.6.8.

Comment: I do get this with Firefox 9.0.1 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Browser problem. I have no problems with FF10 on Linux.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I'm not sure if this could depend on your OS? You made me think of my add-ons, though, and I restarted FF with all add-ons deactivated -- the problem disappeared. Now I don't know if I'll find the time to go through all of them to figure out which one or which combination triggered the problem, but perhaps there's something in general that can avoid this problem happening? It's just curious that it only appeared on one of the three _tags_ tabs.

Comment: I _don't_ get the scroll bars with Firefox 3.6.26 on Win XP.

Comment: @Stephen: Good to know, but FF 3.6 is ["probably unsupported"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) anyway.

Comment: @doncherry: OK (especially because it works). As FF3.6.26 was released 2012/01/28, I had not expected this version to be unsupported. But: does work - no problem!

Comment: @Stephen: Ah, then the page I referred you to might not be precise. I forgot that they continued the 3.6 line with security updates.

Comment: I get this in Firefox 10.0 on Ubuntu 11.10 too.

Answer (score 4):

I don't get this anymore with Firefox 13.0.1 and Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 7. Does anybody still get the scroll bars? Unless they're related to the specific tags that are displayed, the problem seems to be solved to me.